# Complex projective plane: $\mathbb C^2$ vs $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a question about Phillip A. Griffiths - Introduction to algebraic curves.

In [Chapter I.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zndn.jpg), it seems to say $\mathbb C^3 \cup L_{\infty} = P^2\mathbb C$, but later on it says $P^2\mathbb C \setminus L_{\infty} = \mathbb C^2$.

What's going on please?

Guesses:

1. I'm wrong: It's not that 'together' means '$\cup$'.
2. I'm wrong: It's not that $\setminus$ means 'set minus'. (Quotient?)
3. I'm right, and so is the book: 'Together' means '$\cup$' and $\setminus$ means 'set minus'. However, no one ever said $\mathbb C^3 \cap L_{\infty} = \emptyset$, so when we take off $L_{\infty}$ from $P^2\mathbb C$, there's still something to take out of $\mathbb C^3$...sooo actually, $\mathbb C^3 \setminus L_{\infty} = \mathbb C^2$ because $L_{\infty} = $ (or $\cong$) $\mathbb C$ or something.
4. I'm right, but the book: is wrong: it should be both $\mathbb C^2$ or both $\mathbb C^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is (4). There is a typographical error in the first statment it should read
$$\mathbb{C}^2 \cup L_{\infty} = P^2\mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Or $P^2\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thankyou, corrected

Comment: Thanks Mummy the turkey!